# jupyter nbconvert to PDF raises PermissionError: [WinError 5]

Tags: python, jupyter, inkscape, nbconvert

I'm trying to convert a Jupyter notebook into a PDF file but I keep getting the following error:

```
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook ejercicios.ipynb to pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "c:\users\netoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\exporter.py", line 143, in from_notebook_node
    nb_copy, resources = self._preprocess(nb_copy, resources)
  File "c:\users\netoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\exporter.py", line 318, in _preprocess
    nbc, resc = preprocessor(nbc, resc)
  File "c:\users\netoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\preprocessors\base.py", line 47, in __call__
    return self.preprocess(nb, resources)
  File "c:\users\netoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\preprocessors\base.py", line 69, in preprocess
    nb.cells[index], resources = self.preprocess_cell(cell, resources, index)
  File "c:\users\netoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\preprocessors\convertfigures.py", line 45, in preprocess_cell
    output.data[self.to_format] = self.convert_figure(
  File "c:\users\netoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\preprocessors\svg2pdf.py", line 125, in convert_figure
    shell = self.command.format(from_filename=input_filename,
  File "c:\users\netoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 575, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "c:\users\netoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 538, in get
    default = obj.trait_defaults(self.name)
  File "c:\users\netoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1578, in trait_defaults
    return self._get_trait_default_generator(names[0])(self)
  File "c:\users\netoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 975, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\netoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\preprocessors\svg2pdf.py", line 77, in _command_default
    major_verison = self.inkscape_version.split('.')[0]
  File "c:\users\netoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 575, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "c:\users\netoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 538, in get
    default = obj.trait_defaults(self.name)
  File "c:\users\netoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1578, in trait_defaults
    return self._get_trait_default_generator(names[0])(self)
  File "c:\users\netoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 975, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\netoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\preprocessors\svg2pdf.py", line 57, in _inkscape_version_default
    p = subprocess.Popen([self.inkscape, '--version'],
  File "c:\users\netoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "c:\users\netoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1311, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acceso denegado
```

Looks like the default permissions for that command aren't enough to create a process of Inkscape, but I'm already using the command line with administrator privileges.

I was able to convert a notebook to PDF successfully past year, it's the same machine but I was using another version of Python, 3.6 or 3.7, does that have to do to with this?

Answer (score 0):

I reported this issue here https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/1525

My temporary solution was to use the absolute path as a string literal where I installed Inkscape instead of calling `self.inkscape`, in my case the path is `'C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\inkscape.exe'`:
https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/88baf7a9ca724d74c9f890a60d5c3680e8959a14/nbconvert/preprocessors/svg2pdf.py#L57
in that line I have `p = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\inkscape.exe', '--version']`.

I printed `self.inkscape` and the output was `'C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe'`. I thought it was because of the double back slash so I tried `os.path.abspath(self.inkscape)` but it was adding the current path from where I'm calling the command at the beginning. I also tried `pathlib.Path(self.inkscape)` but it didn't work, so I have no idea what the problem could be.